# How to send Notification through Firebase console including Custom data?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have to send a URL in notification and I want upon clicking the notification, the link will be opened immediately by Chrome. Currently, when I click the notification, it only opens my app.

What changes do I have to implement in this code for my desired behavior?

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String title) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: _Suggest_ : Why don't you use `open with` function? And i thought the issue is about "how to open another app while clicking a notification?"